# Bash Script to Convert Milliseconds to Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds

Tags: bash, awk

I wrote the following bash script to convert milliseconds to Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds to make a log file more readable:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ### Constants ###
    CON_DAYS=.0000000115741
    CON_HOURS=.000000277778
    CON_MINUTES=.000066667
    CON_SECONDS=.001

    ### Variables ###
    INPUT="$1"

    cat $INPUT | awk -v CON_HOURS=$CON_HOURS -v CON_MINUTES=$CON_MINUTES -v CON_SECONDS=$CON_SECONDS -v CON_DAYS=$CON_DAYS '
        { $1=substr($0,0,10) }
        { MILLISECONDS = $1 }
        { DAYS = int(MILLISECONDS * CON_DAYS) }
        { MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS - int( DAYS / CON_DAYS ) }
        { HOURS = int(MILLISECONDS * CON_HOURS) }
        { MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS - int(HOURS / CON_HOURS) }
        { MINUTES = int(MILLISECONDS * CON_MINUTES) }
        { MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS - int(MINUTES / CON_MINUTES) }
        { SECONDS = int(MILLISECONDS * CON_SECONDS) }
        { MILLISECONDS = MILLISECONDS - int( SECONDS / CON_SECONDS ) }
        { $1 = DAYS":"HOURS":"MINUTES":"SECONDS":"MILLISECONDS"ms" }
        {print}'
    exit
```

Section of Input File:

```
1882224617mS ATMChannel: [1] CMLinkLayer Rx: 'DialDigits' (ls)
1882224617mS ATMIO:      [1] TONE DIAL (11 digits)
1882224617mS ATMChannel: [1] StateChange Connected->ToneDialing
```

There are several lines of output that shows that it is not working correctly:

```
22:19:224:14:186ms ATMChannel: [1] CMLinkLayer Rx: 'DialDigits' (ls)
22:19:224:14:186ms ATMIO: [1] TONE DIAL (11 digits)
22:19:224:14:186ms ATMChannel: [1] StateChange Connected->ToneDialing
```

After several hours of troubleshooting I am unable to find my error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a sample input file and expected output?

Comment: Sample of input has been added to post.

Comment: The text in the faulty output doesn't seem to be in the input. Can you edit the sample input to include the faulty inputs? Good luck.

Comment: The sample of input has been edited to match the faulty output. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split into millisecond and second, using GNU date, you should be easier to get the result

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="$1"

while read t rest
do
  ms=$(echo $t|sed -r "s/.*(.....)$/\1/")  # get Milliseconds  617mS
  se=$(echo $t|sed -r "s/(.....)$//")      # get seconds  1882224
  days=$(echo $se / 3600 / 24 |bc)

  d="$days:$(date -d "1970-01-01 $se seconds" +%H:%M:%S):$ms"
  echo "$d $rest"
done < $INPUT
```

Comment: Nice and simple, though the days field gets rounded up for some reason?

Comment: Got your point, the date is +1 day than your result. if we need calculate how many days, we need minus 1 .

Comment: +1 Makes sense, last day of 1969 seems to work well.

Comment: Can't you just change to `1969-12-31` rather than get days beforehand?

Comment: I have to avoid to use `date -d ` to get the days(for hours, minutes and seconds it is fine). For example, if more than 31 days, the %d will export the date, not days. So I updated the script and fix the bug.

Comment: @BMW I can't figure out how this works. What is INPUT and $1? What is the argument? Running it on a millisecond value fails. Can you please add context on how this is run? I have no idea how to run this or what it expects.

Answer (score 4):

If execution speed is a concern, this will produce the same output as the accepted answer, but it does it 33x faster on my machine (0.9s vs 30s with a 1000 line file):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)mS/ \1mS/' "$1" | while read sec msec info; do
        for scale in 86400 3600 60 1; do
                num_scale=$((sec / scale))
                sec=$((sec - (scale * num_scale)))
                echo -n "$num_scale:"
        done
        echo "$msec $info"
done
```

The efficiency comes from the following:

1. Separating seconds from milliseconds is done in a single `sed` process that feeds the `while` loop.
2. Parsing out the seconds, milliseconds and the log text is done in a single `read` per line.
3. There are no pipes or sub-processes inside the main loop.
4. Outputting the days, hours, etc., is just done through simple math that doesn't have to be put through the `date` command's parser, formatter, etc.

Although it's not tagged in your question, `perl` is installed on most UNIXes by default and is quite well suited to tasks like these, and even with a quick-and-dirty style it's another step up in speed (0.05s with the same file; 18x faster than my BASH above, and 600x faster than the accepted answer):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
@scales = (86400, 3600, 60, 1);
while (<>) {
        ($sec, $msec, $info) = /^(\d+)(\d{3}mS)(.+)$/;
        foreach $scale (@scales) {
                $num_scale = sprintf("%0d", $sec / $scale);
                $sec -= $scale * $num_scale;
                print "$num_scale:";
        }
        print "$msec$info\n";
}
```

Execution time test and output verification:

```
$ for script in accepted.bash iscfrc.bash iscfrc.pl; do echo -n $script:; time ./$script log_1000.txt >$script.output; echo; done
accepted.bash:
real    0m30.257s
user    0m4.040s
sys     0m8.089s

iscfrc.bash:
real    0m0.881s
user    0m0.672s
sys     0m0.200s

iscfrc.pl:
real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.012s

$ md5sum *.output
e3a05f4f88a9d912f4ba92112dfbf709  accepted.bash.output
e3a05f4f88a9d912f4ba92112dfbf709  iscfrc.bash.output
e3a05f4f88a9d912f4ba92112dfbf709  iscfrc.pl.output

$ tail -n3 *.output
==> accepted.bash.output <==
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMIO:      [1] TONE DIAL (11 digits)
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMChannel: [1] StateChange Connected->ToneDialing
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMChannel: [1] CMLinkLayer Rx: 'DialDigits' (ls)

==> iscfrc.bash.output <==
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMIO:      [1] TONE DIAL (11 digits)
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMChannel: [1] StateChange Connected->ToneDialing
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMChannel: [1] CMLinkLayer Rx: 'DialDigits' (ls)

==> iscfrc.pl.output <==
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMIO:      [1] TONE DIAL (11 digits)
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMChannel: [1] StateChange Connected->ToneDialing
21:18:50:24:617mS ATMChannel: [1] CMLinkLayer Rx: 'DialDigits' (ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't use [cat](/questions/tagged/cat) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for this (unless you were doing the whole thing in an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script).

Try something like

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="$1"
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]+ ]] && days=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)" | bc -l)
  [[ $days =~ '.'[0-9]+ ]] && hours=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} * 24" | bc -l)
  [[ $hours =~ '.'[0-9]+ ]] && minutes=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} * 60" | bc -l)
  [[ $minutes =~ '.'[0-9]+ ]] && seconds=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} * 60" | bc -l)
  [[ $seconds =~ '.'[0-9]+ ]] && ms=$(echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} * 1000" | bc)
  [[ $line =~ 'mS'(.*) ]] && line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  printf "%d:%d:%d:%d:%d" "$days", "$hours", "$minutes", "$seconds", "$ms" 2>/dev/null
  printf "$line\n"
done < "$INPUT"
```

Which produces

```
21:18:50:24:616 ATMChannel: [1] CMLinkLayer Rx: 'DialDigits' (ls)
21:18:50:24:616 ATMIO:      [1] TONE DIAL (11 digits)
21:18:50:24:616 ATMChannel: [1] StateChange Connected->ToneDialing
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far!! I am having 2 problems with the provided script. The first is that column 1's output is now "0:0:0:0:0" for each line. The second is that it is much slower then using awk ( though I can live with that ).

Comment: @socialdtk On same input you posted? Strange, you're running from bash? Though I would go with [BMW's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21505686/3076724) anyway. Maybe some special characters on line, you could try replacing `^[0-9]+` in the first line with `[0-9]+'mS'`